# Finding the moments of a join distribution r.v. ($\bar{X},\bar{Y}$) supposing that ($X_i,Y_i$) are n iid pairs following joint distribution of (1).

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

given $\mu_\bar{X} = 6$, $\mu_\bar{Y} = 8$, $\sigma_\bar{X} = 3$, $\sigma_\bar{Y} = 4$

Find $\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X}, \bar{Y})$ and $\operatorname{cor}(\bar{X},\bar{Y})$

I know that $\operatorname{cor}(\bar{X},\bar{Y}) = \dfrac{\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X}, \bar{Y})}{\sigma_\bar{X}\cdot\sigma_\bar{Y}}$

I'm unsure of how to find the covariance.

Edit:
Progress:

$$\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X},\bar{Y}) = \mu_\bar{X} \cdot \mu_\bar{Y} - \sigma_\bar{X}\cdot \sigma_\bar{Y} = 36$$

$$\operatorname{cor}(\bar{X},\bar{Y}) = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(\bar{X},\bar{Y})}{\sigma_\bar{X}\cdot\sigma_\bar{Y}} = 3$$

I dont know if this works but this is the only way i could get an answer somehow. I honestly don't feel like this is right because that would give it a slope of $4$ and that seems too high.

Comment: What is (1) (the joint distribution)?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer this.